# How do you call the Mozilla webthings REST API?

Tags: mozilla

I'm trying to call the REST API for Mozilla WebThings using PostMan.  According to the documentation, to get a list of things should be a simple GET to /things.

I try a GET to http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx/things

I get a ton of HTML back, designed for displaying in a browser, not a JSON response.  If I just open the URL in a browser, I get an empty but blue page displayed but there's tons of HTML behind it, including buttons, selects, etc.  I didn't dig deeply, just enough to know I'm not getting what I want.  I did look for enough to try to find something instructional to my GET call failing or something but I didn't find anything.

Any readers who have used the webthings REST API and can give me enough to start, I'd sure appreciate it.  I've spent hours on Bing looking for any articles from someone who's done it or any sample code from Mozilla and can't find anything that helps me.

http://192.168.xxx.xxx/things

Comment: You might need to set `Accept: application/json` request header field. That's common in REST APIs.

Comment: Thanks, Dima.  That was the answer.  If you repost your comment as an answer I can vote it up.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I think the question can be closed though. If mozilla docs are clear on the expected request header fields, please flag this to Mozilla 